# Applying a class once a div has been slidetoggled and is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i apply a class that i have set in my css (which is the same as the hover state) if a div i have on slidetoggle is visible?

I have 6 buttons, layout of 3 by 2, my slidetoggle div slide down in the middle of hte 2 rows of 3 and pushes the content down with it, this is all working perfectly, but i would like the one button that has been clicked to have its slidetoggled activated to show the same state as what i have defined in the css for the hover state.

Code.

HTML

```
<div id="row1">

<a href="#!" class="active">
<span id="product1">
</span>
</a>

<a href="#!" class="active">
<span id="product2">
</span>
</a>
//etc etc etc to product 6
</div>
```

CSS

```
#row1 > a:hover > #product1 >#productblueheader > #productlogosblue1
/*#row1 >a.active > #product1 > #productblueheader> #productlogosblue1 */{
    background-image: url(../images/mwprologo.png);
}

#row1 > a:hover > #product1
/*#row1 > a.active > #product1*/ {
    border: 1px solid #e8bb27;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#row1 > a:hover > #product1 > #productstitle
/*#row1 > a.active > #product1 > #productstitle*/ {
    color: #e8bb27;
}
```

And JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.active").removeClass('active');
            $("#product1").click(function(event){
                if($(this).parent('a').hasClass('active')){
                                $(this).parent('a').removeClass('active');
                         }else{
                                $(this).parent('a').addClass('active');
                            }
                $("#product2box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#product3box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#product4box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#product5box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#product6box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                $("#product1box").stop().slideToggle(1000);
                return false;
            });
            });
            });
            });
            });
            });
```

Updated this js, the color is off at the beginning (correct) and goes on when i click the button (correct) now i just need to unactivate it on the second click when i click off it?

Comment: Your html,css,js are not consistent. You should make it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so I can help you.

Comment: You need to add your HTML that has `#product2box` and so on or it would be great if you can create a fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".producthandler").click(function() {
        var ctx = $(this);
        var productboxId = ctx.children().eq(0).attr("id");

        ctx.toggleClass('active');
        $("#" + productboxId + "box").stop().slideToggle(1000);

        $(".producthandler").each(function() {
            var ctx = $(this);
            var producthandlerId = ctx.children().eq(0).attr('id');

            if (productboxId !== producthandlerId) {
                ctx.removeClass('active');
                $("#" + producthandlerId + "box").slideUp(1000); 
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your JS, I think you can change it into this:

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.active").removeClass('active');

    $("#product1").click(function(event){
        //Make sure you put this inside every click function
        $("a.active").removeClass('active');

        if($(this).parent('a').hasClass('active')){
                $(this).parent('a').removeClass('active');
         }else{
                $(this).parent('a').addClass('active');
        }
        $("#product2box").slideUp('slow', function() {
            $("#product3box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#product4box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product5box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $("#product6box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $("#product1box").stop().slideToggle(1000);
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, the active class (which is just an all color set of buttons vs monochrome when off) is on all the time now not just on the click event...@user26409021

Comment: AAAAaaa so close to perfect! Only problem now is that if i refresh the page, before i have clicked on any of the links they are all in colour (aka active) how do i remove that class from the beginning? to only activate on the first click? @user26409021

Comment: Joking, i think i just had my mouse in the hover position haha this still doesnt work... @user26409021

Comment: Well, then I guess you really need to update your question first to give us better understanding on your goal. I just edited my answer to remove `.active` on page refresh/load.

Comment: I think the idea you are suggesting is along the right lines, i just think the last bit of activating the class active isn't targeting it properly just yet...? Im new to all this i dont really know how to word my questions etc.. did you see me post the jsfiddle link above? @user26409021

Comment: Aaa i nearly did it, i shuffled around your code! I'll post what iv go there now hangon!@user26409021

Comment: The button now comes off color and back to monochrome when clicked. BUT. i have made the code so that if i clikc one product then another, the first product will close and the second will open but now the color stays on if i click on a different product to close it and open a new one. the active is only going off with the second click of its own button if that makes sense? @user26409021 thank you so so much for your help also!

Comment: In every click function, don't forget to put something like `$("a.active").removeClass('active');` to remove all active button.. I guess you haven't checked my last edited answer..

Comment: This doesnt work tho, the order is wrong... i will update my question code to show you, i tried to edit your code but i dont know if it worked @user26409021

Comment: Well, I just edited my answer with your ordering and add a solution for your issue.. Try to copy and paste my code, especially for the `#product1`. If this still doesn't work I believe you need to update your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.active").removeClass('active');
                $("#product1").click(function(event){
                    if($(this).parent('a').hasClass('active')){
                                    $(this).parent('a').removeClass('active');
                             }else{
                                    $(this).parent('a').addClass('active');
                                }
                    $("#product2box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product3box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product4box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product5box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product6box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    $("#product1box").stop().slideToggle(1000);
                    return false;
                });
                });
                });
                });
                });
                });
```

This is nearly perfect.. only problem now is that because i have set it up so that when one product is clicked the toggled div slides back up and opens the newly clicked div, now the active class wont go off from unclicking on another product... they turn their own active state off but when i click a different product it the active color state stays on for the first button and opens on the second also then the order is thrown off...